# Autocomplete using TRIE with ability to do middle of the sentence Query?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-structures, trie

Building a new Autocomplete system, and have requirement to search with key words, even if they are in middle of the sentence. I have HUGE list of book titles e.g." Autobiography of Steve Jobs". Instead of typing "Aut" as query prefix, user may choose to type "Steve" and should still get the same result, How to implement using TRIE? Would I need multiple TRIEs? Any help in this regards will be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do this is to add several `input` in your `completion` field. I once had a similar use case with postal addresses. For instance, an address like "1000 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94103" should come up when the user starts typing either of the following tokens:

- 1000
- Market
- Market St
- (also eventually) San Francisco (depending on size)
- (also eventually) 94103 (depending on size)

So in order to support hat use case, the idea was to index a document like this:

```
PUT addresses/_doc/1
{
    "display": "1000 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94103",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ 
          "1000 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94103",
          "Market St, San Francisco, CA 94103",
          "San Francisco, CA 94103",
          "94103"
        ]
    }
}
```

The good thing with addresses is that they have a structure (Street number, street direction, street name, etc). In your case, with book titles, it's a bit more difficult since there's no implicit structure. However, you could simply split your input on each space and index the part that comes after the space (without the stop words). For instance, for "Autobiography of Steve Jobs", you'd index the following inputs:

- Autobiography of Steve Jobs
- Steve Jobs
- Jobs

Concretely,

```
PUT books/_doc/1
{
    "display": "Autobiography of Steve Jobs",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ 
          "Autobiography of Steve Jobs",
          "Steve Jobs",
          "Jobs"
        ]
    }
}
```

That way, when the user types in "Steve" or even just "Jobs", the book would come up. You can also play with weights in order to give more importance to the exact title than other variations.

Try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Well the problem is i have 30 million+ book title and we want to not only do full text search, but also show typeahed type suggestions, say as user types in keystrokes list of books is displayed on the typed prefix ... Hence was wondering how this can be deployed using TRIE or similar data structure (for scalability and fast response)

Comment: You can still do full text search on the `display` field and typeahead suggestions on the `suggest` field. You just have to build the different inputs at indexing time.